# Access 2016 automatically run report with criteria prompt?

Tags: sql, ms-access, macros, vba

I'm working on an Access 2016 database for logging pass/fail conditions in my factory.  I have everything I need if I want to run everything manually, now I want to automate my database.

I've got a report that pulls data from a query.  When I run the report, the query's criteria prompt is triggered, asking for the date in mm/dd/yyyy format.  Manually entering in the info works fine, but how can I create a macro that automatically puts a value into the prompt for me?

I've tried using the Macro design tool to "OpenReport" with the following Where Condition line:

Where Condition = `[DailyReport Query]![LogDate] = Date()`

However, when I run the macro, I still get the prompt to enter in the date.  Am I missing something incredibly simple here?  I'm still searching for the answer so, if I find it, I'll post it.  Any and all help in the meantime is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried putting `Date()` in the query criteria field under Log Date instead of putting it in the macro?

Comment: I honestly didn't think of that...and that is much easier than what I was trying to do.  Thanks for the easy solution! :)

Comment: Glad I could assist you. There's usually more than one way to solve a problem in Access. If I helped solve your issue, please accept my answer as your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, put `Date()` in the query criteria field under Log Date instead of putting it in the macro.